# TYPO3 hook for any files uploading

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18, and I'd like to use a hook which will work when any files uploaded on the site on BE or FE.
Is it possible?
Help me please, how to use?

Comment: Here is the complate example for uploading image For BE and Frontend. https://github.com/helhum/upload_example

Comment: I need hook! It's not what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two answers I can give you here:

You will not find the one hook for every file upload in the frontend, because the uploading in the frontend part of TYPO3 can be done by extensions and they can implement it in every possible way imaginable and do not need to provide a hook for other developers. So sry, for the frontend there is no hook.

The backend however provides a hook in the [\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\File\ExtendedFileUtility](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/7/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_file_1_1_extended_file_utility.html) class. It can be registered in an extensions `ext_localconf.php` like so:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_extfilefunc.php']['processData'][] = \MyVendor\MyExt\Hook\FileUtilityHook::class;
```

where the class `\MyVendor\MyExt\Hook\FileUtilityHook` implements [\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\File\ExtendedFileUtilityProcessDataHookInterface](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/7/html/interface_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_file_1_1_extended_file_utility_process_data_hook_interface.html)
An example implementation could look like this:

```
class FileUtilityHook implements \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\File\ExtendedFileUtilityProcessDataHookInterface{
    /**
     * Post process hook that gets executed when all operations have been done
     *
     * @param string $action The action that got processed
     * @param array $cmdArr The cmdArray contains data about the file, for example $cmdArr['data'] is the file/folder to delete
     * @param array $result The results of all calls to the action handler, for example $result['delete'] = true
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\File\ExtendedFileUtility $parentObject
     */
    public function processData_postProcessAction ($action, array $cmdArr, array $result, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\File\ExtendedFileUtility $parentObject): void {
        if( $action === 'delete' ){
            // something got deleted
        }
    }
}
```

Please be aware that this is a postProcess hook, so all operations have been done already when using this hook.